# Show managed metadata as search refiner SP2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search-results, managed-metadata

I have been trying whole day to configure search, set up the search service application, did a full crawl, had lots of internal errors and after a long day, did an iisreset and finally it was working. Hurray.

Now, my problem is that I want to show managed metadata as search refiners, but none are showing.

I found this post [Managed metadata columns as search refiners](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/fb962eec-6b64-4d8a-9d67-7b74a4840d82/managed-metadata-columns-as-search-refiners?forum=onlineservicessharepoint) but cannot find a tutorial on how to do it.

Can anyone help me?

[Update]
Did the steps described in the first answer, but now came across a new problem. I can see the "Managed Metadata Columns" in the Filter, changed it to my column but still they are not appearing in the Search Refinement Panel.

```
<Category    Title="TopicMM"   
 Description="Managed metadata of the documents"    
Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.TaxonomyFilterGenerator"    MetadataThreshold="3"   
NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="3"    
MaxNumberOfFilters="20"    
ShowMoreLink="True"    
MappedProperty="ows_MetadataFacetInfo"    
MoreLinkText="show more"    
LessLinkText="show fewer" />
```

[Update2]
Silly of me. I forgot to uncheck the Default Configuration checkbox. Hope this helps others though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps you have to perform inorder to work.

- Run Full Search Crawl.
- On Search Admin page > under **Queries and Results** click **Metadata Properties**.
- On the Metadata Property Mappings page click New Managed Property
- Fill in the Property Name: **NameofProperty**
- Under the **Mappings to crawled properties** click the button **Add Mapping**
- In the dialog box, under **Crawled property** name type **NameofProperty**. Click Find. Select the crawled property **ows_NameOfProperty**(Text) and click OK.
- Save the **Metadata Property**
- Now that you have set up the Metadata Property, you need to perform a **full crawl again**. Follow the steps from earlier to do this.
- Once the full crawl had completed, the way to check if it will work in a search it to navigate to your search center.

Complete steps on this link: [Search Refiners with Managed Metadata](http://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2013/04/07/search-refiners-with-managed-metadata/)

Comment: This did work partially. I can see the "Managed Metadata Columns" in the Filter xml, but they are still not appearing in the refinement panel.